# How to append an element inside a link after the first text element with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to append an element - example `<span>extracontent</span>` - inside a link, but only when there is text inside and only and directly after the first text.

There are many combinations, and I handled them with different codes (searching for the place to insert my element):

- simple: `elem.childNodes.length == 1`
- looping through the children: `!currChildren[j].childElementCount && currChildren[j].textContent.trim().length`

**Is it possible to do this with one loop which would handle all situations?**

Samples of the different possibilities with the appended code as expected results:

- Simple text: `<a href="#">Text<span>extracontent</span></a>`
- Icon: `<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i><span>extracontent</span></a>`
- Div containing image and text:

  ```
  <a href="#">
      <div>
          <div><img src="" alt="" width="24" height="24"></div>
          <div>Text<span>extracontent</span></div>
      </div>
  </a>
  ```
- Multiple texts:

  ```
  <a href="#">
      <div><img src="" alt="" width="24" height="24"></div>
      <div>
          <div>Text1<span>extracontent</span></div>
      </div>
      <div>Text2</div>
  </a>
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could recursively parse the DOM tree and append the element whenever you find a text node that isn't empty.

**Edit**: now taking `<i>` elements into account as well (see comments below).

```js
function isTargetTextElement(element) {
  return (element.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && element.textContent.trim().length > 0)
      || element.nodeName === 'I';
}

function appendAfterFirstText(parentElement, elementToAppend) {
  // Browse through all the element's children
  for (const childElement of parentElement.childNodes) {
    // If that node is a non-empty text node, append the element after it and stop
    if (isTargetTextElement(childElement)) {
      parentElement.insertBefore(elementToAppend, childElement.nextSibling);
      return true;
    }
    // Otherwise, do the same starting from that node's children
    if (appendAfterFirstText(childElement, elementToAppend)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a => {
  const elementToAppend = document.createElement('span');
  elementToAppend.textContent = 'extracontent';
  appendAfterFirstText(a, elementToAppend);
});
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div>
    <div><img src="" alt="" width="24" height="24"></div>
    <div>Text</div>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="#">
  <div><img src="" alt="" width="24" height="24"></div>
  <div>
    <div>Text1</div>
  </div>
  <div>Text2</div>
</a>

<a href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Wow, it is great! It seems to work in all cases except the case when there is only a FontAwesome icon inside: `<i class="fa fa-search"></i>`. I'm not sure if that is a text node or not.

Comment: You mean a link with just that empty `<i>` tag inside, nothing else? That is definitely not a text node :)

Comment: I'm trying to add an `or` part to the text node check with a regexp checking for `<i>` element, but can't trigger it. Am I trying on the right place?

Comment: No need for a regex for this, I'll edit my answer to handle `<i>` elements as well, give me a couple minutes.

Comment: There you go, see my edited answer. Used [`Node.nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName). (Or did you need the content to be appended inside the `<i>`?)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Sir, you are my hero for the day! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Happy to help. This was a fun little exercise too :)